# Replacing BB and Chainset only?

Tags: shimano, crankset, drivetrain

Presently my bike has an FSA 19mm piece of junk BB and omega chainset. As this is a unique system it has no compatible parts. The bike uses Tiagra 4500 9 speed for the rest of the components.

If I fit a HTII BB(24MM) and a Sora 9 Speed crankset (50 & 34 tooth like the FSA) will that work or are there any other compatibility issues about not changing the entire set?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, should be fine. Those 19mm BBs are available for replacement though.

Comment: Unfortunately the consumable shims that go between the spindle and bearing are useless and disappear rather quickly so they arent worth keeping.